# how to convert decimal to binary of preferred size in java

Tags: java, binary, integer

i want to print the numbers from `1` to `64` in binary but they should be like this:

```
integer 1 - binary  000001
integer 4 - binary  000100
integer 11 - binary 001011
integer 33 - binary 100001
```

means the binary number should be of six digits and it should add zero in the begining if the answer is not of 6 digits.

Comment: As you don't appear to have asked a question ...good luck?

Comment: As everything in the end is binary on a computer, it's very easy to get bits from any integer value by just using some bitwise operators, like shift and bitwise-and.

Comment: Maybe show us what have you tried so far in order for us to help?

Comment: Integer.toBinaryString(); After that, change your required format.

Comment: i am telling that if i want to convert integer 4 to binary, then i can do it using java.lang.Integer.toString(4,2) method but it shows up "100"in binary but i want the answer as "000100"

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` gets you the binary representation of the int.

If you want to append leading zeros, at best to use `StringUtils` from Apache commons-lang:

```
String str = StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), 6, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to manually calculate equivalent values -

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {

      int preferedSize = 6;

      BitSet bitSet;

      for(int i = 0;i< (1<<preferedSize) ;i++){
          bitSet= new BitSet(preferedSize);
          int count =  0;
          int temp=i;
          while (temp > 0) {
              if ( (temp % 2) == 1 ) 
                  bitSet.set(count);
              temp = temp/2;
              count++;
          }

          StringBuffer bf= new StringBuffer();
          for(count=preferedSize-1; count>=0; count--)
              bf.append((bitSet.get(count)? 1 : 0));

          System.out.println(i +" = "+bf.toString());
  }
```

and using Lukasz's answer, you can get it by iterating it in for loop like this -

```
  int preferedSize = 6;

  for(int i = 0;i< (1<<preferedSize) ;i++){
     System.out.println(i+" = "+StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), 6, '0'));
  }
```

Output -

```
0 = 000000
1 = 000001
2 = 000010
3 = 000011
4 = 000100
5 = 000101
6 = 000110
7 = 000111
8 = 001000
9 = 001001
10 = 001010
11 = 001011
12 = 001100
13 = 001101
14 = 001110
15 = 001111
16 = 010000
17 = 010001
18 = 010010
19 = 010011
20 = 010100
21 = 010101
22 = 010110
23 = 010111
24 = 011000
25 = 011001
26 = 011010
27 = 011011
28 = 011100
29 = 011101
30 = 011110
31 = 011111
32 = 100000
33 = 100001
34 = 100010
35 = 100011
36 = 100100
37 = 100101
38 = 100110
39 = 100111
40 = 101000
41 = 101001
42 = 101010
43 = 101011
44 = 101100
45 = 101101
46 = 101110
47 = 101111
48 = 110000
49 = 110001
50 = 110010
51 = 110011
52 = 110100
53 = 110101
54 = 110110
55 = 110111
56 = 111000
57 = 111001
58 = 111010
59 = 111011
60 = 111100
61 = 111101
62 = 111110
63 = 111111
```